# Python file upload takes date as 'None' when opening a .csv file with excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, file-upload

I made a function to upload .csv files which has the following headers,

> name,pid,quantity,length,width,height,volume,weight,ETA,truck_type,origin,destination

I have created a custom file upload 'reader' function for it:

```
def upload_batch (request):
    template_name = 'classroom/teachers/upload.html'
    prompt = {
        'order': 'Order should be as follows: name,pid,quantity,length,width,height,volume,weight,truck_type,origin,destination'}
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, template_name, prompt)

    csv_file = request.FILES['file']
    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)

    uploaded_by = request.user

    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'):
        _, created = ItemBatch.objects.custom_update_or_create(name=column[0], pid=column[1], quantity=column[2],
                                                               length=column[3], width=column[4], height=column[5],
                                                               volume=column[6], weight=column[7], truck_type=column[9],
                                                               date=column[8], origin=column[10],
                                                               destination=column[11], uploaded_by=uploaded_by)


    context = {}
    return redirect('teachers:upload_batch')
```

This is my custom-manager function:

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def custom_update_or_create (self, *args, **kwargs):
        date_time_value = kwargs.pop('date', None)
        if date_time_value:
            kwargs['date'] = self.get_date_value(date_time_value)
        return super(CustomManager, self).update_or_create(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_date_value (self, value):
        FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', '%d-%Y-%m %H:%M:%S', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m-%Y-%d %H:%M:%S',
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%d/%Y/%m %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
            '%m/%Y/%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S',

            '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', '%d-%Y-%m %H:%M', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M', '%m-%Y-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M',
            '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', '%d/%Y/%m %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%Y/%d %H:%M', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M', '%Y/%d/%m %H:%M',

            '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %p', '%d-%Y-%m %H:%M:%S %p', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S %p', '%m-%Y-%d %H:%M:%S %p',
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p', '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S %p', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p', '%d/%Y/%m %H:%M:%S %p',
            '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p', '%m/%Y/%d %H:%M:%S %p', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %p', '%Y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S %p',

            '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %p', '%d-%Y-%m %H:%M %p', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M %p', '%m-%Y-%d %H:%M %p', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p',
            '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M %p', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p', '%d/%Y/%m %H:%M %p', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p', '%m/%Y/%d %H:%M %p',
            '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M %p', '%Y/%d/%m %H:%M %p', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %p'

        ]
        # input_formats = formats.get_format_lazy('DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS')
        input_formats = FORMATS
        for format in input_formats:
            try:
                print("value is and format is",value,format,self.strptime(value, format))
                return self.strptime(value, format)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                continue

    def strptime (self, value, format):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, format)
```

Now, the only problem is, when I open/edit a '.csv' file using notepad or any other software other than Microsoft Excel, it opens just fine. Here is an un-edited csv file.

[image: csv]

When I open the same file in excel, and save without changing anything, it shows me this warning:

[image: enter code here]

I already have written the code for decoding:

> data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')

Comment: It's just warning you that if you save the file as `.csv` format, it won't retain features specific Excel-only features.

Comment: But, like I said, when save it on excel, my upload function does not take in the date values at all.

Answer (score 0):

> when save it on excel, my upload function does not take in the date values at all

I assume that Excel is changing the date format to something that your `get_date_value` does not support. From a quick look, your year format in Excel is not supported (`%y` -- two digits for year)

To fix this, you can do any of the following:

1. Update date format in Excel before saving to a format that your code supports
2. Support the date format your Excel saves in your code (add `%d-%m-%y %H:%M`)